# jQuery.ready and this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web page that load a lot of javascript files.

Each javascript do a specific action.

I'm using this model in each javascript file:

```
"use strict";

$(function() {
    var self = this;

    // some code

    var func1 = function() {
        // do some action
    };

    var runTimer = function() {
        func1();
        setTimeout(self.runTimer, 60000);
    }
});
```

BUT "this" in this case point to html document and I would like to point to the function itself.

How can I achieve it?

Is there any better "model" to use?

My webpage is like a lot of widgets running at same time and each javascript file run a specific widget.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: What are you trying to do with "this"?

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing a proper reason for you doing this. If you want to assign a function to a variable just use:

```
var functionVariable = function() { ... }
```

Maybe if you tell us why you want to do this out answers will be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've written it looks like you want to call `func1()` every 60 seconds. Rather than set up a function like `runTimer()` that recursively calls `setTimeout`, just use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval). Rather than having the function `runTimer()`, just use:

```
var timer = setInterval(func1, 60000);
```

and if/when you want to cancel this and stop func1 being called, use:

```
clearInterval(timer);
```

From what I can see you're only using self/this to achieve this, and there's a better/more straightforward way of doing this. If there's another reason you want to set self=this, can you add to your code sample or try to clarify what you want to acheive?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [proxy](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) function: it does exactly that